# Не удаётся корректно конвертировать цвет из формата integer в rgb на php

Tags: php, color, hex

Есть задача конвертировать цвет из формата integer (например синий - 3866879) в формат rgb (59, 0, 255). В переменной $color содержится цвет в формате integer.
Использую этот код:

```
$color = '16711680'; 

$c['r'] = $color & 0xFF;

$c['g'] = ($color >> 8) & 0xFF;

$c['b'] = ($color >> 16) & 0xFF;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что большинство цветов конвертируются правильно, за исключением красного цвета и синего и их оттенков.
Например при конвертации красного цвета '16711680' в rgb формате получается синий '0.0.255'. А если поменять местами первое значение с последним, получится правильный цвет, т.е. красный как и нужно. 
Может кто нибудь может подсказать в чём может быть проблема? или может быть есть какое-то другое решение? Код должен быть на php.

Далее у меня цвет уже конвертируется в hex формат из полученных значений:

```
    $R = dechex($r);
    if (strlen($R) < 2)
    $R = '0' . $R;

    $G = dechex($g);
    if (strlen($G) < 2)
    $G = '0' . $G;


    $B = dechex($b);
    if (strlen($B) < 2)
    $B = '0' . $B;
```

И после, из hex формата обратная конвертация в integer :

```
    $color = '#3c00ff'; 
       function hex2int16($str) {
    $num = hexdec($str);
    return ($num & 0x80) ? $num - 65536 : $num;
    }

    echo hex2int16($color);
```

Но вот при обратной конвертации все цвета конвертируются корректно.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Тебе нужно сделать конвертацию integer в hex, и из hex в rgb?

Comment: Нет, нужно из integer в hex, а после обратно из hex в integer. Но т.к. я не нашёл решение конвертации из integer в hex за один шаг, пришлось сначала конвертировать из integer в rgb, а после уже в hex.

Comment: @Let's say Pie Теперь коричневый цвет и его оттенки неправильно конвертируется '4287317267' в hex используя вашу функцию.

Comment: Обновил функцию

Comment: @Let's say Pie Теперь вообще не правильно конвертируются все цвета. Например 'fff0f8ff' такого цвета же вообще не существует.

Comment: Что по вашему должно быть? Взгляните на это https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo5zb.png

Comment: @Let's say Pie Не совсем понятно цвета которые состоят из менее 6 цифр, ваша функция неправильно конвертирует. Пример оранжевый цвет "33023", функция возвращает значение "80ff " Вот как это значение может быть оранжевым цветом? Или я вас не правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Let's say Pie А не могли бы вы мне подсказать как из значения int получить rgb, т.к. если делать напрямую цвета некорректно отображаются.

Answer (score 1):

```
function bcdechex($dec) 
{
    $hex = '';
    do {    
        $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
        $hex = dechex($last) . $hex;
        $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
    }
    while($dec > 0);

    return $hex;
}

echo bcdechex(4293982463); // fff0f8ff
```